# If I'm playing as a fey, would I be considered as possessed by a fey with protection from evil and good, and if so, what happens if I fail the save?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I know based on my previous question that I can still use [detect evil and good](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/detect-evil-and-good&ved=2ahUKEwiFxM_72ICFAxVXkokEHShLCCIQFnoECBMQAQ&usg=AOvVaw08_Q2VCqiLQx8Z0Xg1gf5I) as a fairy, and [dispel evil and good](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dispel-evil-and-good&ved=2ahUKEwi_3-av34CFAxVwJTQIHYLNCTUQFnoECAUQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1EzBPAtO-Yvb6mV3yZDCXP)
directly calls out what happens, but what about [protection from evil and good](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/protection-from-evil-and-good&ved=2ahUKEwjPqfrs34CFAxVrrokEHcynDU8QFnoECBIQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1WsMA11DVTW_MoRfzGeIda)? It says that if the target is possessed by one of the specified creatures, one of which being fey, they have advantage on the next save to be unpossessed.

Am I possessed by myself? If I am, what happens when I'm not? Am I just a soul? What happens to my body? Will casting protection from evil and good on myself as a fairy make me roll to see if I can stay in my body?

I know I'm probably being stupid, but I don't want to risk removing myself from a campaign in the dumbest way possible.

Comment: What did I do wrong?

Comment: I think the reason for the downvotes is because the premise of your question is not based on any known rules. There are no rules regarding whether or not you are in a constant state of "possessing yourself", and as far as I can tell, possession itself has no hardset rules aside from the effects that are described by monster stat blocks. The question would be improved by letting us know why you believe a fey creature would be considered possessing themselves, and the relevant rules of possession.

Comment: Sorry, the only books I have on DND beyond are the free ones plus monsters of the multiverse, as I could only afford one book that wasn't free and I wanted the fairy, so I didn't know if there was a ruling and it was just in a book I didn't have

Comment: No need to be sorry! It's fine to ask questions, and it's fine to get downvoted. It's just imaginary numbers. Sometimes the only way to learn is to ask. Like Thomas said though, sometimes your DM is the best person to ask.

Comment: @TheLittlePeace they are not imaginary numbers! They are _integer_ numbers! :-D

Comment: Don't worry about the downvotes.  If someone doesn't tell you *why* they downvoted you, you don't know.  You don't have enough privilege to see up and down votes (you get it at 1000), but once you do, you'll see that many, many questions get downvotes.  Without explanations, I just think of it as a slight dew of negative energy that we are unfortunately stuck with, and move on.

Comment: @Eddymage they are just as imaginary as this internet cookie I just gave you for that dad joke 

Comment: "If the target is already charmed, frightened, or possessed by such a creature, the target has advantage on any new saving throw against the relevant effect."  Is there a save versus being you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Ask your DM ahead of time for rulings on spells you aren’t sure about.

We can tell you what we think and how we interpret the rules. In this case, it seems quite straightforward that you are not possessed by yourself. However, there is a sure fire way to know how your DM is going to rule on a given rules question: ask them. This site is great for getting consensus on rulings via votes on answers, but we can’t actually tell what your DM will say. But your DM can, so ask them.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice. I'll keep that in mind

Comment: @Tasi And if you do, if you disagree with your DM's ruling they are still there to support the fun in your game. If their rulings prevent you from exploring a character concept you think seems fun I am sure they are happy to discuss tweaking the rules interpretation as long as it doesn't stand in the way of the other players' fun (which in your case I can't see any reason that it would).

Answer (score 18):

### You are not possessed by yourself

You simply *are* yourself. The rules use the common English meaning for words they don't define as game terms. To be possessed, according to the dictionary, means

> (of a person) completely controlled by an evil spirit. "she ran like a possessed person" [Oxford Dictionary]

The possessed is a person that is controlled by another entity, described here as an evil spirit. You are neither an evil spirit, nor are you possessing another entity. You are yourself. Yes, you normally control yourself, but that is as different concept than the one referred to in protection from good and evil: that an evil spirit somehow controls *another* creature, that is not itself.

The reason fey, undead and demons listed in that spell is that creatures of these kinds are typically the ones in folklore (and hence, in the *Monster Manual*) that have the ability to possess another creature. But that is not what is happening if they are just themselves.

Possession causes problems, because without driving out that other entity, you cannot fight it directly, you can only fight and harm the possessed creature, which may be innocent or even your friend. None of that is in play when you are just talking about yourself.

Comment: Yeah, I was scratching my head reading the question.  The language of the spell mentions that if the creature is already possessed, they gain advantage on their next saving throw against the effect.  For that to matter I was thinking they are going throughout the campaign without worrying about protection and rolling saving throws against remaining in their own body without advantage.  I thought OP must be doing something strange like playing a fey that is possessing another creature but I couldn't figure out how that would work.